# Certificate error in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

After the last upgrade of Crystal Reports for Visual Studio, every time I open the report in design view I'm getting multiple certificate errors (see picture below). The errors comes from the SAP web site productupdates.sap.com, which indeed has certificate expired. But I cannot find any references to this site in my project. How to get rid of them? This doesn't happen on all computers, only on mine.

Posted this question in SAP forum - no answer.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

https://productupdates.sap.com/ is expired.

See whether **Crystal Reports->Check for Updates on Start Up** is checked

Turning it off and re-opening the solution appears to stop the continuous certificate security alerts.

[image: Visual Studio Crystal Reports Turn Off Check for Updates]